# Suppose f(x) is continuous and differentiable on (a,b) and lim|f(x)|= infinity as x approaches a+. Prove that f'(x) is unbounded on (a,b)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

so far for this problem i have said let c,d be in (a,b) and $d\gt c$

suppose f'(x) is bounded by M( i want to eventually get a contradiction)

$\mid f'(x)\mid= \frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c} \le M$

but not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the mean value theorem? Suppose $x < y$. If $f$ is continuous on $[x,y]$ and differentiable on $(x,y)$, then there is a $z$ in the open interval $(x,y)$ such that 
$$ f'(z) = {f(y) - f(x) \over y - x}$$.

Do you need more help? (I am assuming that $a$ and $b$ are bounded...)

Comment: yes, so far i have that much down but im unsure as to how to find the contradiction to show that the MVT is greater than M which is some bound when assuming it is bounded

Comment: Hold $y$ fixed. What happens to $f(x)$, and so to the ration on the right of the equality if $x$ is close to $a$? And I should have pointed out: the denominator can't get too large, because of the assumption on $a$. Does this help?

Comment: The fact that $a$ is finite, and thus  that there is a bound $y - a$ on the denominator $y-x$, matters: as a counter-example (without the bound on $a$), take the function $f(x) = x$. The function is without bound on the real line (of course), and the derivative $f'$ is (of course) bounded.